# Shadow line with images as vertical separator btw DIVs - how to place top and bottom images?

Tags: css

I'd like to have a thin "shadow" line between my DIVs, as separator. Since I'd like the shadow line to be thiner and with more opacity at the top and at the bottom, I have created 3 images: middle shadow, top shadow and bottom shadow. Problem: I don't know how to place the "top shadow" image at the top of "middle shadow" and "bottom" shadow at the bottom (without multiple DIVs). I'm attaching an image done in fireworks where you can see and example of the shadow line.Many tks[image]

```
div#content-center {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: khaki;
    background: transparent url('images/middle_shadow.png') repeat-y top left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also might be abel to do this with the `:before` and `:after` psedo-elements.  [Read up on them here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/) if you aren't familiar.

```
#content-center{
    background:  url('images/shadow_repeat.png') center right repeat-y;
}

#content-center:before,
#content-center:after{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: none;

    /*size these to be what you need*/
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#content-center:before{
    top:0;
    background-image: url('images/shadow_top.png');
}

#content-center:after{
    bottom:0;
    background-image:url('images/shadow_bottom.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried but without success, see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/Jcq2D/

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a complete solution, just a way to get you started since you didn't give any other code you had with it.  I've updated the fiddle and made some notes in the CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/Jcq2D/2/

Comment: Thanks Chris, that works well and the comments that you added were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Give multiple backgrounds:

```
background:  url('images/middle_shadow.png') top left, url('images/middle_shadow2.png') center left,url('images/middle_shadow3.png') repeat-y bottom left;
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I tried your suggested solution but doesn't seem to be working, see jsfiddle based on your proposal: http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/tZADk/